# Iterating all Play Framework routes in Test

Tags: java, routes, integration-testing, playframework-2.3

Is there any way to Iterate all described services in `routes` file? URL and HTTP methods are needed.

I need this feature for running some integration test.

I am using Play for Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not easily. I managed to hack my way through it a while ago(no scala know-how). I'll post that code maybe it can be of use.

```
public static List<String[]> parseRoutes() {
    scala.Option<play.core.Router.Routes> option = Play.application().getWrappedApplication().routes();
    if (option.isDefined()) {
        play.core.Router.Routes routes = option.get();
        scala.collection.Seq<scala.Tuple3<String, String, String>> doc = routes.documentation();
        scala.collection.Iterator<scala.Tuple3<String, String, String>> it = doc.iterator();

        List<String[]> listOfRoutes = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        while(it.hasNext()) {
            scala.Tuple3<String, String, String> tuple = it.next();
            //tuple._1() is the method and tuple._2() the url... tuple._3() is the controller name
            String[] route = {tuple._1(), tuple._2()};
            listOfRoutes.add(route);
            Logger.debug("route -> " + Arrays.toString(route));  
        }
        return listOfRoutes;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Don't worry about the `.iterator()` showing a `The method iterator() is ambiguous for the type Seq<Tuple3<String,String,String>>`. It compiles just fine in play.